# Implementing Transpose - Compile-time Error

Tags: haskell, transpose

I'm working on `transpose` from [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules).

```
-- transpose - rows becomes columns and vice-versa
-- transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  
-- [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Here's my attempt:

```
transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' [[]] = [[]]
transpose' ys = [map head' ys] ++ transpose' (map tail' ys)
         where head' []     = []
               head' (z:zs) = z
               tail' []     = []
               tail' (z:zs) = zs
```

However, I don't understand the compile-time error associated with the `map head' ys` call.

```
> :l Transpose.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Transpose.hs, interpreted )

Transpose.hs:5:22:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `[a0]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
          at Transpose.hs:3:15
    Expected type: [[a0]] -> a
      Actual type: [[a0]] -> [a0]
    In the first argument of `map', namely head'
    In the expression: map head' ys
    In the first argument of `(++)', namely `[map head' ys]'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Could you please explain to me what's wrong with my code per the compile-time warning?

Comment: Consider your definition for `head'`.  What exactly do you want it to be doing?  What type do you want it to have?

Comment: The type signature of `head'` must be `head' :: [a] -> a`. You can't take the head of an empty list. Similarly you can't take the tail of an empty list either. Remove the definitions `head' [] = []` and `tail' [] = []`.

Comment: you'll have the same problem with `tail'`.  Try defining them at the top level and giving them signatures, that should help you track down the issue.

Comment: @AaditMShah and bheklilr, thanks for pointing out the type issue with head. However, I'll need to find a better way (maybe `Maybe`) to deal with empty lists. Otherwise: `Prelude> map head [[]]
[*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list`

Comment: You could always filter out empty lists from `ys` before processing it: `let zs = filter (not . null) ys in ...`.

Comment: You could consider list comprehensions. There it is possible to pattern-match lists without failure.